# PHP - How to show a var's value?

Tags: php, asp.net, sql, var, adodb

I have an SQL statement and the result stored in a var. However, I'm new to ADODB's syntax and would like to know how to output the var's value somewhere else on my webpage. I'm trying to convert ASP syntax to PHP and I can see how it's done in ASP, I just need a PHP equivalent.

#### ASP SQL code:

```
 vtypeSQL="select * FROM voices where voicetype ='" &voiceid& "'"
 Set vtypeRecordset = Connect.Execute (vtypeSQL) // I need the PHP equivalent of this
```

#### ASP / HTML code:

```
<div id="location">
   Boys >> <%=vtypeRecordset("voicetypetxt")%> //Outputs the field 'voicetypetext'
</div>
```

#### The ADODB code:

```
 try{

 $con = new COM("ADODB.Connection"); 
 $con->Open(
   "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" .
   "Data Source=../database/myDB.mdb");

 $vTypeRST = new COM("ADODB.Recordset");
 $vTypeRST->Open("SELECT * FROM voices WHERE voicetype = '" . $voiceID. "'", $con, 1, 3);
   while (!$vTypeRST->EOF) {
     echo $vTypeRST["voicetypetxt"]->Value;
   $vTypeRST->MoveNext;
   }

 } catch (Exception $e){
   echo 'ERROR:'.$e->getMessage();
   file_put_contents('connection.errors.txt', $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
 }
```

#### PHP / HTML

```
<div id="location">
  Boys >> <?php $vTypeRST.GetString; ?>
</div>
```

I know $vTypeRST.GetString; is the wrong syntax - but you get the idea of what I'm trying to do (echo the $vTypeRST value). Could anyone please point me in the right direction on the correct syntax to use?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Using a var_dump($vTypeRST); outputs: OBJECT(COM)#3 (0) { }

EDIT: Thanks to John Conde the issue has been resolved. The code I needed to work was this:

```
echo $vTypeRST["voicetypetxt"]->Value;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I've already tried that and brings back the error: CATCHABLE FATAL ERROR: OBJECT OF CLASS COM COULD NOT BE CONVERTED TO STRING IN (E:\xxx\xx\xxx\xx) ON LINE 222.

Comment: so the COM class doesn't have a `__toString()` method, and you'll have to rummage around inside the object to find the stuff you want, via `var_dump($vTypeRST)`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. As previously mentioned i'm new to ADODB syntax and i'm really unsure how to do what you've said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$vTypeRST["voicetypetxt"]->Value;` contains the value you are looking for:

```
<div id="location">
  Boys >> <?php echo $vTypeRST["voicetypetxt"]->Value; ?>
</div>
```

[`echo()`](https://www.php.net/echo) will output all parameters you pass to ti (e.g. variables, strings).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've already tried that and I get the error message: CATCHABLE FATAL ERROR: OBJECT OF CLASS COM COULD NOT BE CONVERTED TO STRING IN (E:\xxx\xx\xxx\xx) ON LINE 222. I know the SQL works because when the while loop is triggered, it brings back the correct value; it's just trying to display that value in my div...

Comment: Do a `var_dump($vTypeRST);` and show the output in your question.

Comment: Please see my revised question.

Comment: Doesn't look like there are any values in your response. Are you sure your query is working properly? I did update my answer to reflect what I think is correct, though.

Comment: Just seen your edited answer. Yeah, i'm positive the sql query works and that little bit of code has worked!! Thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend var_dump or print_r to echo for debugging, because *echo'ing* a false(bool) value gives you nothing, while var_dump() will give you the data type (bool), and the value.